# unsafe value used in a resource URL context with angular 5

Tags: angular, iframe, angular5

Want to embed this Iframe in my template, but getting error
here is iframe code, which is to be placed inside the template of the component

```
<iframe [src]="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{show.trailer}}"
 width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

here is type script  file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Show } from '../show';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ShowService } from '../show.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-show-details',
templateUrl: './show-details.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./show-details.component.css']
})
export class ShowDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

show: Show;

constructor( 
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private showService: ShowService
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.getShows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the show variable defined?

Try to change your iframe code to this

```
<iframe [src]="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{show?.trailer}}"
 width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

show?.trailer

Evaluates if the show variable != null or undefined

Comment: yes it defined in mock.show.ts file in form of array

Comment: tried the show?.trailer  , giving error "Quotes are not supported for evaluation!"

Comment: please help me out their is any other way

Comment: did you use it in the interpolation context {{show?.trailer}}

Comment: actaully i have resolved this issues by creating pipe in angular and importing { DomSantizier } , but now i am facing another issues with the browers

Comment: that is "Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; " , please tell me what is it

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/security They have a tutorial how to embed iframe.